# Can't compile with catkin_make

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'd like to use `catkin_make` command to compile a package,
So I create a folder `src` in my workspace  with `mkdir`, then use `catkin_init_workspace` to initialize the package.
But when runing `catkin_make` I obtain the following error even if my `src` folder is empty:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em:23: error: <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: Multiple packages found with the same name "ros":
- ros
- share/ros
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/em.py", line 3276, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/em.py", line 3274, in main
    invoke(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/em.py", line 3257, in invoke
    interpreter.wrap(interpreter.file, (file, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/em.py", line 2262, in wrap
    self.fail(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/em.py", line 2253, in wrap
    callable(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/em.py", line 2326, in file
    self.safe(scanner, done, locals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/em.py", line 2368, in safe
    self.parse(scanner, locals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/em.py", line 2388, in parse
    token.run(self, locals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/em.py", line 1403, in run
    interpreter.execute(self.code, locals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/em.py", line 2565, in execute
    exec(statements, self.globals)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/topological_order.py", line 111, in topological_order
    for path, package in find_packages(space).items():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 92, in find_packages
    raise RuntimeError('\n'.join(duplicates))
RuntimeError: Multiple packages found with the same name "ros":
- ros
- share/ros
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  
  execute_process(/home/limiarf/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
  "/usr/bin/python" "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/em.pyc" "--raw-errors"
  "-F" "/home/limiarf/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.py"
  "-o" "/home/limiarf/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.cmake"
  "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em") returned
  error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake:25 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:29 (em_expand)
  CMakeLists.txt:63 (catkin_workspace)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/limiarf/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/limiarf/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

What should I do?

Thanks
Younès

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209577/can%27t-compile-with-catkin_make/) by [younes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20031/younes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-20**:
For future questions: please use the *preformatted text* button on the bar to format console copy/pastes. It's the button with `101010` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error you get tells you something pretty clear :

```
Multiple packages found with the same name "ros":
- ros
- share/ros
```

Did you try to investigate that? It should be a conflict.

---

Originally posted by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) with karma: 381 on 2015-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0